# Is it possible to reduce a button size in tkinter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-button

I'm working on a little text editor and currently making the buttons, on the picture bellow the 'B' button for bold. I would like to reduce his size in order to make him fit his true size, like a square box, and get rid of the extra-height.

[image]

How could I go below this size that seems to be the default minimum? Both the frame and button height are set to 1 and expecting an integer, so I'm not allowed to go below with something like 0.5.

```
top_menu = tk.Frame(root)
bold_button = tk.Button(top_menu, text='B', font=('EB Garamond ExtraBold',)) #here a tuple because tkinter needs it when the font name have multiple spaces
bold_button.pack(side='left', padx=4)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `width` and `height` attributes are in units of characters (eg: `1` means the size of one average character). You can specify the width and height in units of pixels if the button has an image.

A button can have both an image and text, so a simple trick is to add a one-pixel transparent pixel as an image, which will then allow you to specify the size in pixels.

The `padx` and `pady` options also contributes to the size of the button. If you are trying to get a precise size, you need to set those to zero.

Here is a simple example:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("200x100")

pixel = tk.PhotoImage(width=1, height=1)
toolbar = tk.Frame(root)
toolbar.pack(side="top")
for size in (12, 16, 24, 32):
    button = tk.Button(toolbar, text=str(size), width=size, height=size,
                       image=pixel, compound="center", padx=0, pady=0)
    button.pack(side="left")

root.mainloop()
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: You just solved my problem, and something like ninety percent of my previous issues, so thank you very much for your dedication about tkinter on this site Bryan Oakley!

Answer (score 0):

I think you could try to use a `ttk.Button` and give it a `ttk.Style` and set the font size:

```
s = ttk.Style()
s.configure('my_button', font=('Helvetica', 12))
b = ttk.Button(..., style='my_button')
```

Answer (score -1):

Configuring a button (or any widget) in Tkinter is done by calling a configure method "config"

To change the size of a button called button1 you simple call

```
button1.config( height = WHATEVER, width = WHATEVER2 )
```

If you know what size you want at initialization these options can be added to the constructor.

```
button1 = Button(self, text = "Send", command = self.response1, height = 100, width = 100)
```

Comment: As I said, the height and width are already set to 1 by default and we can't go below.